# Generator to Tuple to List?

Tags: python, generator

I have a method that takes a generator, converts it into a tuple to sort it, then into a list. It works perfectly, but being as I am fairly new to the Python world, I keep asking myself if it is worth doing or not...

```
@property
def tracks(self):
    if 'tracks' not in self.cache:
        s = Search(Track)

        q = {'query': self.name}
        if self.artists[0]['name'] != 'Various Artists':
            q.update({'artist': self.artists[0]['name']})
        _, tracks = s.search(**q)

        tracks = sorted(((int(i.track_number), i) for i in tracks))

        self.cache['tracks'] = [t for n, t in tracks]

    return self.cache['tracks']
```

I could care less about `track_number` as the `track[i]` already has that information, I'm just using it to sort the track list. `s.search(**q)` generates a generator of `Track` instances from a `json` object, I sort the track list, then I turn it back to a generator for an output.

Is there a better way? Should I just deal with the track number being there?

```
for _, track for Album.tracks:
    # work with track
```

**Update**:

The way the backend API works it only requires the first artist in the search, on a collaborated album of various artists, it just gives `Various Artists`, hence the `self.artists[0]['name']` which is usually the only item in the list anyways.

And I know `q['key'] = value` is better practice than `q.update({key: value})`, originally it was taking more than a few items, hence the use of `.update()`, I just never changed that part.

The method is being called in `Album.tracks` where `s = Search(Track)` tells the `Search` class to use the `Track` class.

```
## models.py
class Album:

    @property
    def tracks(self):
        s = Search(Track)

## search.py
class Search(Service):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
```

Instead of:

```
## models.py
class Album:

    @property
    def tracks(self):
        s = Search('track')


## search.py
from models import *

MODELS = {
    'album':  Album,
    'artist': Artist,
    'track':  Track
}

class Search(Service):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = MODELS[model]
```

`Search` calls a backend api service that returns queries in `JSON objects` which then generates instances based on what `self.model` is set to. `s = Search(Tracks)` tells `Search` to call the `track` api and iterate through the results and return `Track` instances.

The main question here is, the current method that I have, is it doing too much? It generates the `Track` instances from the `Search.search()` generator, which is a somewhat abstract method for calling the api service for `Album`, `Artist`, and `Track` so it does nothing but generating instances based on what model it is given. Which is why I then have `Album.tracks` create a tuple so that I can sort the tracks base on track number, and then return a list of the tracks, nice and sorted.

**Main point:** Should I be worried about getting rid of the track numbers and just return the tuple, or is it fine to return the list?

**Update 2:**

```
class Album:

    @property
    def tracks(self):
        if 'tracks' not in self.cache:
            s = Search(Track)

            q = {'query': '', 'album': self.name}
            if self.artists[0]['name'] != 'Various Artists':
                q['artist'] = self.artists[0]['name']

            _, tracks = s.search(**q)

            self.cache['tracks'] = sorted(tracks, 
                key = lambda track: int(track.track_number))

        return self.cache['tracks']

class Track(BaseModel):

    def __repr__(self):
        artist = ', '.join([i['name'].encode('utf-8') for i in self.artists])
        track  = self.name.encode('utf-8')
        return '<Track - {artist}: {track}>'.format(artist=artist, track=track)
```

Calling it:

```
album_meta = Search(Album)

results = album_meta.search('making mirrors', artist='gotye')

for album results:
    print album.tracks

''' Output
[<Track - Gotye: Making Mirrors>,
 <Track - Gotye: Easy Way Out>,
 <Track - Gotye, Kimbra: Somebody That I Used To Know>,
 <Track - Gotye: Eyes Wide Open>,
 <Track - Gotye: Smoke And Mirrors>,
 <Track - Gotye: I Feel Better>,
 <Track - Gotye: In Your Light>,
 <Track - Gotye: State Of The Art>,
 <Track - Gotye: Don’t Worry, We’ll Be Watching You>,
 <Track - Gotye: Giving Me A Chance>,
 <Track - Gotye: Save Me>,
 <Track - Gotye: Bronte>] '''
```

Comment: This function would be easier to review if you told us a bit more about the Album class that it is defined on, what is it used for, what the performance considerations are, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create intermediate list for sorting:

```
tracks = sorted(((int(i.track_number), i) for i in tracks))
```

and then chose only one column:

```
self.cache['tracks'] =  [t for n, t in tracks]
```

I think this would be better to replace two statements above:

```
self.cache['tracks'] = sorted(tracks, key = lambda track: int(track.track_number))
```

Also, `q.update({'artist': self.artists[0]['name']})` doesn't look good. It can easily be replaced with `q['artist'] = self.artists[0]['name']`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to hear. A way to reduce/combine it all. I felt like it was doing too much repetitive work generating a list to sort, then generate another list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what your question is. You already remove the track numbers from the value you return with:

```
self.cache['tracks'] = [t for n, t in tracks]
```

Other notes:

- I'm a little worried about the line `s = Search(Track)`. What is it searching? Does the constructor for `Search` have access to some sort of singleton database? This is a place where dependency injection would probably improve the code.
- Why only `self.artists[0]`? In what circumstances would there be multiple artists? Why would you ignore results for the other artists? What if an artist participated in multiple albums with the same name but a different set of collaborators?
- The `q.update({...})` line is a bit odd. I would find it considerably clearer to read `q['artist'] = ...` instead.

Comment: The question has been updated with the in-depth explanation.